# A question about SolrJ range query?

Tags: solr

We can use solr range query like:
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=queryStr&fq=x:[10 TO 100] AND y:[20 TO 300]
or :
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=queryStr&fq=x:[10 TO 100]&fq=y:[20 TO 300]

How to make this range query by using solrJ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [addFilterQuery() method](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html#addFilterQuery(java.lang.String...)) on the SolrQuery class. Just pass the filter query as is ("`x:[10 TO 100] AND y:[20 TO 300]`")